# Search for an un-allocated time period (minutes)

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I use a scheduler (calendar) in a WinForms application (vb.net) and save appointments (startDateTime & endDateTime) to a MySql DB.

During the process of making an appointment, I need to check if a certain resource (e.g: a Room) is available for a certain period of time (minutes) on a particular day.

I have looked here for possible solutions that fits my scenario, however, all solutions pertain to searching for entries within a particular time period.

I store the StartTime and EndTime for an appointment to the DB as well as any required resources for that appointment.

I can have multiple resources (e.g: more than one Room) and would like to be able to find a room with an un-allocated time period should the default (or selected room) resources not be available for that time period.

A time period can vary from 10 min up to 2 hours, but it will always be a set period for the type of appointment and resource, e.g:
Appointment: Board Meeting

**Resource:** Board Room

**Start Time:** 02/02/2019 09:00:00

**End Time:** 02/02/2019 10:00:00

Any help would be appreciated.

Code I am fiddling with

```
SELECT (TIME(b.appStartTime) - TIME(a.appEndTime)) as timedifference, 
a.appID, a.appOwnerKey, a.appEndTime, b.appStartTime, a.appSubject, 
a.appDescription, a.appToolTip, a.appCategory, a.appImg, a.appPatWaiting

FROM cusAppointments a 
INNER JOIN cusAppointments b ON b.appID = (a.appID + 1)
WHERE (DATE(a.appStartTime) = DATE(NOW()) AND
       DATE(b.appEndTime) = DATE(NOW()))
AND (TIME(b.appStartTime) - TIME(a.appEndTime)) >= 15000
AND a.appOwnerKey = 'Admin .'
ORDER BY a.appStartTime ASC;
```

**EDIT:**
This is not working because in my mind I should be working with two record sets of the same table ordered on StartTime then substract EndTime of RecordSet A's rowid from the StartTime of RecordSet B's rowid + 1.

Comment: Have you checked https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: @Mary: The problem is not doing the actual calculation because I already have that part sorted, the problem is that I need to calculate the time difference between 2 non-consecutive records. This means that I can not work on the recID because appointments are made for random times. Please refer to my EDIT.

Answer (score 0):

After some consideration and realising that there were a few things I did not take into account, I've decided to rather take the processing to the client.

Things I did not take into account:
1. StartOfDay Time (Start of Office Hours)
2. EndOfDay Time (End of Office Hours)
3. Get First Booking - to check for an un-allocated time period between First Booking and StartOfDay
4. Get Last Booking - to check for an un-allocated time period between Last Booking and EndOfDay

I've used a simple If..Else statement block to implement the logic and it takes only 11 code lines to check for everything.
First I check for First Booking and then check to see if I have an open time period between the First Booking's StartTime and StartOfDay time.

The Second check is for the Last Booking to see if there is an opening between the Last Booking's EndTime and EndOfDay time.

The third part is to process all bookings between the First and Last Booking.
            (1) Check if there is a TimeSlot available between the first returned record and the Start Of Day
            '   - Check if we have the first record (j=0)
            '   - Check if myEndTime is less or equal to dbStartTime of first record
            '   - Check if myStartTime is greater or equal to StartOfDay
            '   - Check the Time Difference between dbStartTime of first record and StartOfDay and check if
            '       myTimeSlot is less or equal to that time

```
        If j = 0 AndAlso myEndTime &lt;= dbStartTime AndAlso
            myStartTime &gt;= StartOfDay AndAlso (dbStartTime - StartOfDay) &gt;= myTimeSlot Then
            txtResults.AppendText("Found Time Slots" &amp; vbCrLf)
            'Check for LAST record and do similar as for FIRST record
        ElseIf j = clReadFromDB.tmsData.Rows.Count - 1 AndAlso myEndTime &lt;= EndOfDay AndAlso
            (EndOfDay - dbEndTime) &gt;= myTimeSlot Then
            txtResults.AppendText("Found Time Slots" &amp; vbCrLf)
            'Check for a time slot inbetween the FIRST and LAST record
            '   - We don't have to bother with checking for StartOfDay or EndOfDay
            '   - Check if myStartTime &gt;= dbEndTime of the Current Record (j)
            '   - Check if myEndTime &lt;= dbStartTime of the Next Record (j+1)
            '   - Check if myTimeSlot is &lt;= to the time difference between dbDStartTime of Current Record
            '     and dbStartTime of the Next Record
        ElseIf myStartTime &gt;= clReadFromDB.tmsData.Rows(j).Item(2) AndAlso
            myEndTime &lt;= clReadFromDB.tmsData.Rows(j + 1).Item(1) AndAlso
            (clReadFromDB.tmsData.Rows(j + 1).Item(1) - clReadFromDB.tmsData.Rows(j).Item(2)) &gt;= myTimeSlot Then
            txtResults.AppendText("Found Time Slots" &amp; vbCrLf)
            lblStatus.Text = Convert.ToString(clReadFromDB.tmsData.Rows(j + 1).Item(1) - clReadFromDB.tmsData.Rows(j).Item(2))
        Else
            lblStatus.Text = "Time Slot not found"
            txtResults.AppendText("Time Slot Not Found" &amp; vbCrLf)
        End If
```

I will use the above code as the foundation logic because this runs through all the bookings on the DB. It also uses the First Booking as the initial check instead of the Calendar Time the user selected for the new Booking.

Thank you to those who tried to assist, even though your suggestions did not bring me closer to a MySQL solution, it did however broaden my knowledge of MySQL.